# Change Date Format In fileMaker 11

Tags: filemaker

I want importing data from Excell file in that file format of date are as follows :
  Year-Month-Date ex: 2011-09-19,
 I want to change it format like month/date/year 
 i tryed Date , month, year function for extracting individual day, year month but it's not working.

Thanks
Nishant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to import the value into an extra text field and convert the data using the Replace function to massage the data post-import.

Perform Replace Function:

GoodDate = middle ( TextDate ; 6 ; 2 ) & "/" & Right ( TextDate ; 2 ) & "/" & Left ( TextDate ; 4 )

Where GoodDate = a valid date field and TextDate = the field containing the imported data

Answer (score 0):

I assume here Fechaseguimiento Contains date format:2011-09-19

**Substitute ( Trim ( Substitute ( MiddleValues ( Substitute (Fechaseguimiento; "-" ; "¶") ; 2 ; 1)  & MiddleValues ( Substitute (Fechaseguimiento ; "-" ; "¶") ; 3 ; 1)    &LeftValues (Substitute (Fechaseguimiento; "-" ; "¶");1) ; "¶" ; " ") ); " " ;"/")**